# stringstrings package redefines math symbol(s)

Tags: math-mode, stringstrings

I am loading [`stringstrings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/stringstrings) package in my document and the double vertical bar `\|` (in math mode) is printed as |0 (single vertical bar followed by zero). I checked the `stringstrings.sty` file and noticed indeed the following lines

```
\def\PipeCode{0}
\def\EncodedPipe{\EscapeChar\PipeCode}
\def\Pipe{|}
\let\|\EncodedPipe
```

Below, two minimal working examples showing the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Without {\tt stringstrings}: $\|$ \(\|\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
With {\tt stringstrings}: $\|$ \(\|\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

I suppose `stringstrings` does it due to some string manipulation issues, but is there a way to restore the original symbol, compatibly with the purposes of the package? Besides, are there any other redefinitions I should be aware of?

**Edit:** I sort of fixed the issue by redefining the command `\|` myself in the preamble:

```
\let\doublebar\|
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\def\|\doublebar
```

but I am afraid it might clash with the package. Moreover, [page 16 of the manual](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/stringstrings/stringstrings.pdf#page=16) lists (some of?) the redefinitions, but I couldn't understand how the thing is supposed to be fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I did that package when I was young and foolish, which is to say, before I knew about this site.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `\|` anyhow: `\lVert` and `\rVert` are better (they need `amsmath`). On the other hand, there are alternatives to `stringstrings`.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I am in fact loading `xstring` as well, but due to some issues with expansion and my not-so-high expertise with TeX hacks I found `stringstrings` package very useful for what I was looking for.

Comment: @AndreasT Maybe you can ask about those issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "save" the definition of `\|` before you load the `stringstrings` package using, for example, `\let\pipe\|`. After loading `stringstrings` you can now use `\pipe` instead of `\|`.

Here's a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\pipe\|
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
With {\tt stringstrings}: $\|$ \(\|\) $\pipe$
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

After loading `stringstrings` you could put `\let\|\pipe` but this could, conceivably, break something defined by `stringstrings` so I suggest using `\pipe` instead. Instead of `\pipe` you can, of course, call this anything you like - although I'd recommend avoiding existing LaTeX command names. For example, `\let\cow\|` would work equally well.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for your prompt reply, this is what I also thought. I just find it difficult to convince the other co-authors to type `\pipe` or `\cow` :) in place of `\|`, so I guess I'll take the risks of directly redefining `\|`.

Comment: @AndreasT Pity, `\cow` has a certain appeal...